# Are C# events synchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

There are two parts to this question:

1. Does *raising* an event block the thread, or does it start execution of EventHandlers asynchronously and the thread goes continues on at the same time?
2. Are the *individual EventHandlers* (subscribed to the event) run synchronously one after another, or are they run asynchronously with no guarantee that others aren't running at the same time?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, they are synchronous.

To answer your questions:

1. Raising an event does block the thread if the event handlers are all implemented synchronously.
2. The event handlers are executed sequentially, one after another, in the order they are subscribed to the event.

I too was curious about the internal mechanism of `event` and its related operations. So I wrote a simple program and used `ildasm` to poke around its implementation.

The short answer is

- there's no asynchronous operation involved in subscribing or invoking the events.
- event is implemented with a backing delegate field of the same delegate type
- subscribing is done with [`Delegate.Combine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1eh4771(v=vs.110).aspx)
- unsubscribing is done with [`Delegate.Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.remove(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Invoking is done by simply invoking the final combined delegate

Here's what I did. The program I used:

```
public class Foo
{
    // cool, it can return a value! which value it returns if there're multiple 
    // subscribers? answer (by trying): the last subscriber.
    public event Func<int, string> OnCall;
    private int val = 1;

    public void Do()
    {
        if (OnCall != null) 
        {
            var res = OnCall(val++);
            Console.WriteLine($"publisher got back a {res}");
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        foo.OnCall += i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"sub2: I've got a {i}");
            return "sub2";
        };

        foo.OnCall += i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"sub1: I've got a {i}");
            return "sub1";
        };

        foo.Do();
        foo.Do();
    }
}
```

Here's Foo's implementation:

[image]

Note that there is a *field* `OnCall` and an *event* `OnCall`. The field `OnCall` is obviously the backing property. And it's merely a `Func<int, string>`, nothing fancy here.

Now the interesting parts are:

- `add_OnCall(Func<int, string>)`
- `remove_OnCall(Func<int, string>)`
- and how `OnCall` is invoked in `Do()`

### How is Subscribing and Unsubscribing Implemented?

Here's the abbreviated `add_OnCall` implementation in CIL. The interesting part is it uses [`Delegate.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1eh4771(v=vs.110).aspx) to concatenate two delegates.

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance void 
        add_OnCall(class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,string> 'value') cil managed
{
  // ...
  .locals init (class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,string> V_0,
           class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,string> V_1,
           class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,string> V_2)
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldfld      class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,string> ConsoleApp1.Foo::OnCall
  // ...
  IL_000b:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Delegate [mscorlib]System.Delegate::Combine(class [mscorlib]System.Delegate,
                                                                                          class [mscorlib]System.Delegate)
  // ...
} // end of method Foo::add_OnCall
```

Likewise, `Delegate.Remove` is used in `remove_OnCall`.

### How is an event invoked?

To invoke `OnCall` in `Do()`, it simply calls the final concatenated delegate after loading the arg:

```
IL_0026:  callvirt   instance !1 class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,string>::Invoke(!0)
```

### How exactly does a subscriber subscribe to an event?

And finally, in `Main`, not suprisingly, subscribing to the `OnCall` event is done by calling `add_OnCall` method on the `Foo` instance.

Comment: @KFL, it still unclear, I was just about to leave the same comment as Alex.  A simple "Yes, they're synchronous", would be helpful

Answer (score 82):

This is a general answer and reflects the default behavior:

1. Yes, it blocks the thread, if the methods subscribing to the event are not asynchronous.
2. They are executed one after the other. This has another twist: If one event handler throws an exception, the event handlers not yet executed will not be executed.

Having said that, every class that provides events can choose to implement its event asynchronously. [IDesign](http://idesign.net) provides a class called [`EventsHelper`](https://www.idesign.net/Resources/Downloads/GetDownload/1823) that simplifies this.

***[Note]** this link requires you to provide an e-mail address to download the EventsHelper class. (I am not affiliated in any way)*

Comment: I have read a few forum posts, from which two have contradicted the first point, while not providing a proper reason. I don't doubt your answer, (it matches with what I have experienced so far) is there any official documentation on the first point? I need to be certain about this, but I have difficulties on finding anything official on this exact matter.

Comment: @AdamL.S. It is a matter of how the event is called. So it really depends on the class providing the event.

Answer (score 15):

The delegates subscribed to the event are invoked synchronously in the order they were added. If one of the delegates throws an exception, the ones following **will not** be called.

Since events are defined with multicast delegates, you can write your own firing mechanism using

```
Delegate.GetInvocationList();
```

and invoking the delegates asynchronously;

Answer (score 13):

Events are just arrays of delegates. As long as delegate call is synchronous, events are also synchronous.

Answer (score 9):

In general, events are synchronous. However there are some exceptions, such as `System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed` event being raised on a `ThreadPool` thread if `SyncronisingObject` is null.

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Events in C# run synchronously (in both cases), as long as you don't start a second thread manually.

Comment: What about I use an async event handler? Will it then run in another thread? I have heard about "Async all the way", but it seems like async event handlers have their own thread? I don't understand :/ Can you please enlighten me?

Answer (score 4):

Events are synchronous. This is why the event lifecycle works the way it does. Inits happen before loads, loads happen before renders etc.

If no handler is specified for an event, the cycle just blazes through. If more than one handler is specified, they will be called in order and one can't continue until the other is completely finished.

Even asynchronous calls are synchronous to a degree. It would be impossible to call the end before the begin is completed.